# How to install python-devel for 2.7 version after upgrade to python 2.7 on CentOS

Tags: python, centos6, yum

CentOS 6.7 ships with python 2.6.6, I've upgrade to python 2.7.6 following the tutorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-python-2-7-6-and-3-3-3-on-centos-6-4

After upgraded the python version, I want to install python-devel package for python 2.7, so I run the command:

```
yum search python | grep -i devel
yum install python-devel.x86_64
```

However it seems that the package version doesn't change (still 2.6.6), here is the message:

```
$ yum install python-devel.x86_64
Loaded plugins: security
Setting up Install Process
Package python-devel-2.6.6-64.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You could :

```
yum install centos-release-SCL
yum install python27 python27-scldevel
```

or search your packages

```
yum search python27*
```