# Howto package a python2.7 project for installation on Centos 6

Tags: python-2.7, centos, package, distutils

How do I package a python2.7 project for installation on CentOS 6.7?

I plan on deploying a python2.7 package onto CentOS 6.7 systems that have had python2.7 installed from `SCL` along side the python2.6 needed for the system (as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32522417/how-to-install-python-devel-for-2-7-version-after-upgrade-to-python-2-7-on-cento)).

So far, I've tried

- using `distutils` on a CentOS 6.7 machine to make an rpm (`bdist_rpm`) -- but that's tyring to use python 2.6.
- using `distutils` to make an rpm on a different machine with python2.7 only installed -- the resulting rpm cannot be installed since `rpm` on the CentOS machine assumes python2.6